# Lost in desert - charge the phone with car battery

Tags: battery-charging, charger, cellphone

First of all I'm not a student nor a engineer.

Pretend I'm lost in the desert with just a car with a broken engine.
The battery of my phone is over.

Is there any chance I can survive (charging the phone a little bit to call for help) or I am a dead man?

If so, how?

Comment: Rip apart the car radio, build a crude voltage regulator with the components (there may well be one in there ready to use), wire it up to the power input of the phone.

Comment: When you go to the desert, you get yourself a car charger for your phone...

Comment: Use a spanner to cause shorts across the batter to create electromagnetic interference. Learn Morse Code.

Comment: There is a proposal on Area 51 you may be interested in: [MacGyvering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74621/macgyvering)

Comment: If you got your 12 V soldering iron, some solder and flux with you, then @Majenko-notGoogle 's solution is very good.

Comment: Various materials could be used to make a resistor to limit current flow. OR you could tap into the battery mechanically to get 6V which is easier to use. I could without doubt find some way to do this. You could also make a spark gap transmitter IF you understood what was required.

Comment: My winter/beater car requires a 5-sided key to remove the radio. I don't normally have a soldering iron in the car (the butane one sits in my office). If I had a 5-sided key and a soldering iron and solder around, I'd sure as heck have some USB cables, a Li-ion reserve power pack, or other stuff to charge a cell phone. Stripping a USB cable and using a few AA cells might work. I once built a charger using AA cells, toilet paper roll and galvanized wire to recharge an oddball camera battery to get a few photos in Borneo (the Iban ex-headhunters were a little short on strange Japanese cells).

Comment: While it's so obvious that it's not worth saying because people 'just don't want to listen', this is NOT a question about "... the use of electronic devices ..." and it IS a question re electronic (or electrical) design. **IF** people don't want questions like this here, or do not wish newcomers to feel welcome, or don't want people from Italy (unlikely) or whatever, they should either say so explicitly so a new user gets some decent guidance and a feeling that they are at least a little welcome (IF in fact they are). As it it this type of response is inept, impolite and unproductive ....

Comment: ...., unless 'setting a high bar' is part of what is desired. | Spehro's excellent Borneo ex-head-hunter anecdote is a superb example of what Giorgio was asking about and of what people can do and should be able to do in emergencies. I have cobbled together chargers in Chinese hotel rooms when the original was 8000 km away (no ex head hunters in view), got people's car started by substituting a coil of available wire for a blown ignition ballast resistor and lots of other fun things. Making a USB charger starting with a dead car **IS** something that Spehro could do. If that's not suited ....

Comment: .... to this site we should SAY so - not just kick people down the stairs (yet again) as is our wont.

Comment: @kingbob Modern cellphones usually conform to the "USB" charging standard and require ~+ 5V DC input to charge. Car battery cells provide ABOUT 2.xV each. From around 2.0V or even less when low on charge to 2.2 2.3 maybe more if fully charged. When the car motor is running and the battery well charged V is usually about 13.8V or 2.3V/cell. If you drill/poke/hack into the battery to expose intercell connections or if the battery has these exposed (uncommon nowadays) you can use 2 or 3 cells to make a lower than 12V battery. ...

Comment: ... Two cells MAY be enough to allow charging and will probably always be safe. 3 cells may be needed and may be high enough to damage the phone. | A series resistor may be made from various conductive material to reduce current or voltage (both effectively). Overall, with some playing and knowledge an effective charger could be made. | THEN there is direct LiIon battery charging. Also possible. IF you know enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my car I have a splitter with a couple car outlets and a couple 2A USB outlets, as well as a tiny 120V inverter. The power for those devices, to run phones, tablets, notebook computers (I would normally have 3-4 such devices in the car) comes from the car battery when the engine is not running.

There is plenty of energy in a healthy fully-charged car battery (or a laptop battery) to charge a cell phone, it's a matter of having the correct gadgets around to convert the voltage to the required level. It's unlikely something like that could be Edit: jerry(sic) jury-rigged in the field very easily, but I've done stranger things.

Comment: The phrase is "[Jury Rig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rig)".

Comment: @Majenko-notGoogle as **your** reference says "also jerry rigging"... an acceptable variant. Don't go all prescriptivist now.

Comment: "jerry rigging" is a 20th century combination of "jerry built" and "jury rigged". The two phrases have very different origins and have nothing to do with each other. It is incorrect (though "accepted") to combine them. But I guess a phrase, even an incorrect one, has to start somewhere.

Comment: Once it's accepted it's no longer incorrect, it's just a part of English. BTW, as a former regular at alt.usage.english I was aware of the etymology of the term.

Comment: Kids round here use "Could of done" instead of "Could have done" - it's become accepted, by them at least - is it right?

Comment: Nope, at least until it gets into a real reference. 'Literally' is the one that really grates on me. 'I literally died' -  should I call your next-of-kin?

Comment: Religion should be pursued in some other group.